# .htaccess rewriter rule working in localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

My .htaccess file. I have index.php and movies.php. www.website.com/movies working fine in both localhost and live server.
but www.website.com/movies/movie-title working perfectly in localhost but not in live server. I don't know the problem.
In movies.php page, i'm showing the list of titles if we use www.website.com/movies and i'm trying to show single element if we access www.website.com/movies/movie-title by trying to use $_GET['u'].

## Turn Rewrite Engine On

RewriteEngine on

## Rewrite for index.php

RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [NC,L]

## Rewrite for moviespage.php

RewriteRule ^movies$ movies.php [NC,L]

## Rewrite for movies.php?u=xxxxx

RewriteRule ^movies/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ movies.php?u=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it as if the .htaccess file doesn't exist? If it's the latter, try adding a typo into the file and saving and retrying. If it still acts like there's no file, then your web server might not be Apache it it might not be configured to allow htaccess files

Comment: Its not throwing any errors but it shows same list of data even if using /movies or /movies/title

Comment: please check the link http://www.peacockmattresses.com/

Comment: Have you tried updating movies.php to log the contents of $_GET["u"] and debug the flow? Maybe it's not the rewrite but rather how PHP is handling the data...

Comment: You also might want to institute a base href to make sure that any relative-path dependencies like JS files are being loaded from the proper path instead of trying to be loaded from the relative "movies" subfolder (and being handled by the htaccess)

Comment: in movies.php page i have static list of images. i'm trying to show $_GET['u'] but nothing happened. No result showing. and i don't have any subfolder named movies.

Comment: i'm trying this appoach
http://www.developphp.com/video/Miscellaneous/Semantic-URL-htaccess-Tutorial-SEO-Friendly-and-Clean-Links

Comment: Change movies.php to just be: <?php print_r($_GET); die(); ?> and then try to reproduce the issue. Also, do you have ANY other content in your htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: What about the url with parameters ?

Comment: example: <a href="http://webhost.com/example?id=10">link</a>. As long as your links are without extensions, it is not a problem.

Comment: please check the link it showing the same list of data.
http://www.peacockmattresses.com/

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of**

```
RewriteRule ^movies/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ movies.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

**Try This**

```
RewriteRule ^movies/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /movies.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

`/movies.php` will let the server understand which url, to be exact, need to be rewritten.
Since every page on live server is identified via '/' (forward slash) and the file extension (.php, in this case).

In the syntax,

L = to stop processing the rule further

NC = Process rule to next with case-insensitivity